# Выбор кнопки radio в input через Tab и Enter

Tags: javascript, css3, html5

> Задача: при помощи `Tab` можно выбирать нужный платёж и после выбора нажать `Enter`, чтобы этот платёж отметился в кнопке `radio`.

Проблема 1. При навигации при помощи `Tab` отмечаются поочередно только 2 первых `input`, а потом отметка куда-то слетает и через клик по окну снова возвращается и выделяет `input` подчёркиванием.

Проблема 2. При выделении `input` предыдущие выделения должны пропадать, а они сохраняются.

Проблема 3. По нажатию на `Enter input radio` должен выделяться через `checked`.

```js
var one = document.getElementsByTagName('span');
var counter = 0;


document.addEventListener('keydown', function(event){
  if(event.keyCode === 9) {
      for(i=0; i < one.length; i++) {
        one[counter].classList.add('active');
      };
    counter++;
  }

});
```

```css
.active {
  border-bottom: 1px dotted #000;
}
span {
    padding: 5px;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 150px;
}
```

```html
  <input type="radio" name="payment">
  <span>Оплата наличными</span>
<br>
  <input type="radio" name="payment">
  <span class="text">Банковский перевод</span>
<br>
  <input type="radio" name="payment">
  <span class="text">Банковский перевод №2</span>
<br>
  <input type="radio" name="payment">
  <span class="text">Банковский перевод №3</span>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ответы на проблемы:

1) Инпуты типа "radio" с одинаковым именем(`name`) воспринимаются как один элемент, и это стандарт. При `tab` будет перемещаться только на выбранный инпут или на первый, если выбранного нету. Для перемещения надо использовать стрелки.

2) Можно подчеркивание организовать только с помощью `css`. Это удобнее.

3) Инпут с типом радио выбирается при нажатии на пробел. Это стандарт.

Менять стандартное поведение не рекомендуется.

Пример кода выделения без использования `javascript`.

```css
input[type="radio"]:checked+span {
  border-bottom: 1px dotted #000;
}

label {
  padding: 5px;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 250px;
  border-bottom: 1px dotted transparent;
}
```

```html
<label>
<input type="radio" name="payment">
<span>Оплата наличными</span>
</label>
<br>

<label>
<input type="radio" name="payment">
<span>Банковский перевод</span>
</label>
<br>

<label>
<input type="radio" name="payment">
<span>Банковский перевод №2</span>
</label>
<br>


<label>
<input type="radio" name="payment">
<span>Банковский перевод №3</span>
</label>
```